# Python running an SSH command to a group using Fabric module

Tags: python, networking, raspberry-pi, paramiko, fabric

I'm trying to run commands to two raspberry Pi's as a group using the `Fabric` module. I'm trying to learn how to use the `Group` method but I think I'm doing something incorrectly because when I run the following code:...

```
import fabric

b = fabric.connection.Connection("192.168.3.151", port=22, user="pi", \
    connect_kwargs={"password" : "Raspberry"})
c = fabric.connection.Connection("192.168.3.123", port=22, user="pi", \
    connect_kwargs={"password" : "Raspberry"})
pool = fabric.group.SerialGroup(b, c)
pool.run("touch /home/pi/Desktop/new_file65.txt")
pool.close()
print("hi")
```

I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/invoke/config.py", line 98, in __getattr__
    return self._get(key)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/invoke/config.py", line 165, in _get
    value = self._config[key]
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/invoke/config.py", line 154, in __getitem__
    return self._get(key)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/invoke/config.py", line 165, in _get
    value = self._config[key]
KeyError: 'rsplit'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    pool = fabric.group.ThreadingGroup(b, c)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fabric/group.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.extend(map(Connection, hosts))
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fabric/connection.py", line 246, in __init__
    shorthand = self.derive_shorthand(host)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fabric/connection.py", line 416, in derive_shorthand
    user_hostport = host_string.rsplit("@", 1)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/invoke/config.py", line 110, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(err)
AttributeError: No attribute or config key found for 'rsplit'

Valid keys: ['connect_kwargs', 'forward_agent', 'gateway', 'load_ssh_configs', 'port', 'run', 'runners', 'ssh_config_path', 'sudo', 'tasks', 'timeouts', 'user']

Valid real attributes: ['cd', 'clear', 'client', 'close', 'config', 'connect_kwargs', 'connect_timeout', 'create_session', 'cwd', 'derive_shorthand', 'forward_agent', 'forward_local', 'forward_remote', 'from_data', 'gateway', 'get', 'host', 'is_connected', 'local', 'open', 'open_gateway', 'original_host', 'pop', 'popitem', 'port', 'prefix', 'put', 'resolve_connect_kwargs', 'run', 'setdefault', 'sftp', 'ssh_config', 'sudo', 'transport', 'update', 'user']
```

I think I'm making a simple mistake and would appreciate any guidance with grouping connections! Thanks!

Comment: Are you using `fabric` or `fabric3`?

Comment: Also, is there any particular reason you're not using the fabric env?

Comment: @2ps I'm using `fabric` and it is version 2.1.3. For whatever reason the fabric env won't work for me. Whenever I call the `fab` command in command prompt it doesn't find the command. However the module imports fine for python use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of things here.  To use a `fabfile.py` and run commands using `fab`, you have to make sure to decorate your commands with `@task`.  Here's an example:

--- in fabfile.py ---

```
from fabric.decorators import task
@task
def greet():
    print('Hello, Matt!')
```

When you want to make changes to the fabric environment within the fabfile.py (i.e., at run-time in python code), you have to use the execute pattern

```
from fabric.decorator import task
from fabric.operations import run
from fabric.context_managers import env
def touch_file():
    run("touch /home/pi/Desktop/new_file65.txt")

@task 
def manage_pis():
    env.hosts = [ ... ]
    execute(touch_file)
```

That should be enough of a starting point to use the `env`.

Comment: What if I don't want to use it as a fabfile.py though and want to instead embed it into another python script to run automatically

Answer (score 1):

`SerialGroup` expects `string` not `Connection` so you need

```
import fabric

pool = fabric.group.SerialGroup("192.168.3.151", "192.168.3.123", user="pi", 
                                  port=22, connect_kwargs={"password": "Raspberry"})

pool.run("touch /home/pi/Desktop/new_file65.txt")
pool.close()
print("hi")
```

You can also use `login@host` if you need different users. But you can't use different passwords.

```
pool = fabric.group.SerialGroup("pi@192.168.3.151", "pi@192.168.3.123", 
                                  port=22, connect_kwargs={"password": "Raspberry"})
```

Documentation: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.4/api/group.html#fabric.group.SerialGroup